# Should this question with a related duplicate be closed or not?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

I have come in a little discussion on a [specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42362726/993547). I wonder if it warrants closing or not. We can't quite agree in the comments so I thought I'd ask here.

Given reasons to close:

- The duplicate answers the question actually asked;
- The question is too broad.

Given reasons to reopen it:

- The duplicate just gives a very specific answer, and doesn't answer the slightly different requirements;
- The duplicate just about finding one item from a list, not a subset of, or strings.

Community, what do you think? Does this question needs to be closed or not? To prevent accusations of having a personal interest in the question being reopened, I removed the answer I have posted.

Comment: The question is too broad and I'd say if we are struggling to know how to answer the question it is also unclear. At best it should be marked as duplicate to at least get them onto the right track.

Comment: @Bugs I disagree that it is too broad. It seems clear that they are asking to randomly choose a given number of items from a larger number of items.

Comment: @MatthewWatson based on the comments there is a misinterpretation as to what the OP wants, hence why unclear. After reading through some of the answers as well it does clear it up. For me it's too broad because it doesn't show much effort and although the OP does seem to know what they are after, they haven't done much to try and achieve that.

Comment: @MatthewWatson to put it into context would you answer if the question read just `Can Random pick a random assortment of, strings or char's?` Because that's basically all they have asked with quite a bit of noise round it.

Comment: Thanks for taking the discussion to Meta.

Comment: Thank you for being clear in your reasons to close. It was very helpful to me @CodeCaster

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is:

> select a random assortment of items [from a collection], the number of which being left up to the user

The idiomatic way to do this is to do a proper shuffle of the source collection, then take the first N items. A bad way (in terms of both performance and randomness) to shuffle a list is to order by `Random.Next()` or `Guid.NewGuid()`.

Despite the title of the question, what is being asked here is definitely not *"Can the Random class return strings?"*. Answering *that* question is feeding into an XY problem, without showing understanding to the OP's underlying problem, which is explained in their question text.

Now as for the actual duplicate, in hindsight (and with the motivation shown above) I agree the question I chose ([Access random item in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019417/access-random-item-in-list?noredirect=1&lq=1)) was not the best target. The second answer does exactly what the OP asks for, but with an improper implementation. I get trigger-happy with duplicate-votes on questions that show little research effort, and am aware of that.

But just as security (*"I can't read the result, so it must be properly encrypted, amirite?"*), random is a poorly understood subject. *"The result isn't ordered like it was at the start, so it must be random, right?"*, so you cannot trust the upvotes on the answers that do contain code.

The question [Select N random elements from a List<T> in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48087/select-n-random-elements-from-a-listt-in-c-sharp) is also a poor duplicate. The first few answers contain theoretical discussions and/or poor implementations, only the seventh answer contains actual, non-broken code.

[Given a list of length n select k random elements using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17763664/given-a-list-of-length-n-select-k-random-elements-using-c-sharp) is a good duplicate. [Randomize a List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt) too, but only answers the question at hand partially.

Comment: If the title doesn't reflect what the actual question is why nobody edits it?

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be marked as a duplicate of [Select N random elements from a List<T> in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48087/select-n-random-elements-from-a-listt-in-c-sharp) rather than the answer actually marked as a duplicate.

I do NOT think that the question is too broad. It is clearly asking this question:

`How do I randomly choose N items from a selection of P items (where N <= P)?`

Comment: The code you posted to the question being discussed exists in at least two other answers of yours. Are you sure you shouldn't have voted to close as a duplicate of those questions instead of posting the code as an answer again? Also, the question you link to has nice theoretical discussions and all, but you'll have to scroll down at least five answers for a reasonable implementation. Not a good duplicate.

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes, I am saying that the question should be closed as a duplicate (I didn't find the best duplicate answer right away when searching for it; your suggestions are are better)